# Clickhouse can't get messages from Kafka with TabSeparated formatting

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, clickhouse

I send messages to Kafka from my Spring Boot application

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("uniqTopic123", "testKey", "Test\tTest");
future.addCallback(
        (v) -> System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + v),
        (v) -> System.out.println("FAIL: " + v)
);
kafkaTemplate.flush();
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=app.1
kafka.server=<kafka_host>:9092
kafka.producer.id=kafkaProducerId
```

**Configuration**

```
@Value("${kafka.server}")
private String kafkaServer;

@Value("${kafka.producer.id}")
private String kafkaProducerId;

@Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
private String kafkaGroupId;

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    //props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProducerId);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(
            new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs()));
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

In logs I can see messages like:

*SUCCESS: SendResult [producerRecord=ProducerRecord(topic=uniqTopic123, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = true), key=testKey, value=Test Test, timestamp=null), recordMetadata=uniqTopic123-0@1]*

But my listener doesn't catch any messages

```
@KafkaListener(topics="uniqTopic123")
public void msgListener(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record){
    System.out.println("test ======> " + record.value());
}
```

And the table in ClickHouse is empty. My ClickHouse tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (key String, message String)
ENGINE = Kafka('<kafka_host>:9092', 'uniqTopic123', 'app.1', 'TabSeparated');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (key String, message String)
ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY key;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW consumer TO test_table AS
SELECT key, message FROM test;
```

What is wrong in my code?

UPD.: Kafka Tool shows that messages are in Kafka
[image]

**UPD**:
**The mistake was in absenсe of linefeed at the end of message "Test\tTest\n"**

Comment: firstly I would make sure that topic exists and contains some events: to check it can be used [Kafka Tool](https://www.kafkatool.com/) or cli command *docker run confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic foo --from-beginning --max-messages 5*.

Comment: Ye, I use Kafka Tool. It shows that tyhe messages are in Kafka. Please, see my update at the end of question.

Comment: try to add a line feed at the end message - *"Test\tTest\n"* and test it again. Look at the log *cat /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log*.

Comment: Linefeed  helped! Thanks!

Comment: no problem, I glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was in absenсe of linefeed at the end of message "Test\tTest\n"